Using A Proof Assistant as a Learning Aid
I don't see that anyone has asked this before, but if I have missed something please let me know.
tl;dr - Can you use a proof assistant (like Lean) as a tool to learn math rigorously, and improve proof writing skills?
For reference I am in my last year of math undergrad and I feel like proofs and rigor are my weakest link right now. I struggled my way through an intro to real analysis course, but I want to sharpen my skills and improve myself as a mathematician. I purchased Tao's Analysis I & II, to self study, but I have run into the problem of not really knowing if my proofs are good or not.
I had the idea that I would work on some proof from the book, then write them up in a proof assistant such as lean and then have trustworthy feedback on what I need to do to fix up whatever holes might exist. I dont really know how proof assistants work though so I'm curious what the SE community thinks of this idea.

you still need to interact with humans to improve your skills - Lean etc are wonderful tools, but not for teaching you

@user8268 I agree wholeheartedly, however one cannot always rely on having someone there to proof read their work. I don't know anything about lean etc, but I cant help but feeling if I study and write up a bunch of proofs that unknowingly suck, then I am not really studying as well as I think I am. So I'm curious how much value it has in supplementing (not replacing) human feedback.

This is only a very soft advice - if it's possible, try to interact with others not just for checking your work, but also more directly; you can either work together with other students, or perhaps you have a system of tutorials or exercise classes. I really don't think that Lean can help you check your proofs at this stage, but you can of course try to learn it - perhaps it's a kind of thing which you like and just learning how to use it will improve your "formal proving skills".  (But this is not a math question.)

Interestingly enough, here is a video by T. Tao discussing machine assisted proofs.  Some mention of Lean is made, among other topics:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGke7Q08hko  Might be a useful perspective to consider.
